# Child Genotypes

Tags: code-golf

**The Challenge**

Everybody loves genetics, right? In this challenge, you will be given the genotypes of two parents. You must find each possible genotype of a child produced by the parents. You must account for dominant and recessive alleles as well as incomplete dominance and codominance.

An example input for the parents could be:

```
R'RxRr
```

Parent one (on the left) has a incompletely dominant R allele and a dominant R allele. Parent two (on the right) has a dominant R allele and a recessive allele.

Each parent is separated from the other by an x. The input will not contain an x allele.

An incompletely dominant allele will be followed by an apostrophe ('). Codominant alleles just refers to multiple different types of alleles combined together (A and W for example).

**Rules**

- Shortest code wins (measured in bytes).
- Each possibly genotype must be separated from the other genotypes by a comma.
- Phenotypes don't matter.
- Any letter can be used in the input except for x (which differentiates the parents).
- Duplicate genotypes should only be printed once.

  - Duplicates contain the exact same letters of the same case and type of allele. IF you have WY and YW in your answer, they are considered duplicates.
- No more than three different letters will be used in one input.
- The order of the letters in the output does not matter.
- Answer can be in the form of a string or an array.

**Examples**

Input 1 (the previous example):

```
R'RxRr
```

Output 1:

```
R'R,R'r,RR,Rr
```

Alternate output 1 (array):

```
{R'R,R'r,RR,Rr}
```

Input 2:

```
RWxRR
```

Output 2:

```
RR,WR
//Or an array, whichever you want
```

Input 3:

```
WYxY'y
```

Output 3:

```
WY',Wy,YY',Yy
//Once again, an array is fine
```

Comment: Can the output be an array?

Comment: Sure. I'll add that to the rules.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76428/all-possible-ways-to-interleave-two-strings duplicate, flagged as

Comment: @KennyLau Are you sure? I don't see how they're all that similar.

Comment: Well, the only difference is that the "characters" can be two units long.

Comment: @KennyLau No, this challenge has a few more requirements; for example, it requires you to take dominant and recessive alleles into account. ("You must account for dominant and recessive alleles as well as incomplete dominance and codominance.") The other challenge seems simpler.

Comment: I think it just requires you to remove duplicate.

Comment: @NuffsaidM8 Can you add some examples of dominant/recessive allele test cases which can demonstrate that it's not just a simple case of "removing duplicates" as Kenny alludes to? It would also allow people to more easily verify that their code meets all the corner cases.

Comment: *Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange*! This is a nice first challenge.

Comment: @Chris example two demonstrated duplicates. When you cross the parents, RW and RR would appear twice each. The challenge requires that you only print each once, as shown in the output.

Comment: @NuffsaidM8 That's just removing duplicates after doing a Cartesian product. Is there an example where a deduplicated Cartesian product is not an adequate solution?

Comment: I think you need to explain the problem more clearly. Does lowercase stand for recessive? What are codominant alleles? Why does the output of the first case have three results?

Comment: @Chris Not that I can think of, all the challenge requires is removing those duplicates. To answer your questions don, a lowercase letter always stands for a recessive allele, you can easily Google codominance to get an explanation and the outputs will only have less than three outputs if one of the output is duplicated, in which case you must remove one of the two

Comment: It's my biology class, all over again.

Answer (score 6):

### Pyth, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
{msSd*Fc:z".'?"1\x
```

[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7BmsSd%2aFc%3Az%22.%27%3F%221%5Cx&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=R%27RxRr%0ARWxRR%0AWYxY%27y)

```
         z          get input
        : ".'?"1    regex match for any character followed by an optional '
       c        \x  chop on the element "x", resulting in [["R'","R"],["R","r"]]
     *F             splat over Cartesian product, resulting in pairs of "genes"
                      from the first "parent" and from the second
 m  d               map over each resulting pair...
   S                sort (so that we can dedup later)
  s                 concatenate
{                   remove duplicates
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>114</s> <s>112</s> <s>104</s> <s>90</s> 88 bytes

```
f=>(c=new Set,[z,y]=f.split`x`.map(b=>b.match(/.'?/g)),z.map(e=>y.map(g=>c.add(e+g))),c)
```

Thanks to Doorknob, Downgoat, Kenny Lau and Neil for helping me golf this down a bit :)

Comment: The `\w` can be replaced by `.` (because there will not be `ψ'`)

Comment: ... which means you can shorten the regex to `/.'?/g` (note the removed i flag, which was unnecessary in the first place), the one I used in my answer.

Comment: The `i` (case-insensitive) tag can be removed as well (as well as the `g` global tag?).

Comment: Thanks guys! @KennyLau, you can't take the `g` flag off, otherwise it results in undefined

Comment: This fails for `ABxAB`, since `AB` and `BA` are identical.for the purposes of the challenge.

Comment: You don't need the `()`s for a single argument to a `=>` function. `a` is unused and can be removed. You can also use `c.push(x,y)` instead of `c.concat([x,y])`, but it might turn out shorter to map over `d[1]` or simply to `add` them directly to the `Set`.

Comment: Your inner Code Reviewer must be at war with yourself

Comment: You maybe able to do `[z,y]=` instead of `d=`, and then use `z` instead of `d[0]` and `y` instead of `d[1]` but I'm unsure if it saves any bytes

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>82</s> 77 bytes

Anonymous function, takes the input string as its argument.

Edited to properly account for `ABxAB`.

-5 bytes from @Doorknob.

```
->g{a,b=g.split(?x).map{|s|s.scan /.'?/}
a.product(b).map{|s|s.sort*""}.uniq}
```

Comment: `.map(&:sort).uniq.map &:join` is shorter as `.map{|x|x.sort*''}.uniq`.

Comment: Nice! I learned a new Ruby shorthand today!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5 - 196 bytes:

```
def b(r):import itertools,re;r=[];[r.append(h)for h in itertools.permutations(re.sub("(?<=[a-zA-Z'])(?=[a-zA-Z])",' ',r.replace('x','')).split(' '),2)if h[::-1]not in r and h not in r];return r
```

A nice one liner, using some regular expressions.

**Note:** Around each letter with an apostrophe are double quotes, and I hope that's okay (e.g., in the output, `R'` would come out as `"R'"`). Also, for the last test case, it returns `[('W', "Y'"), ('W', 'y'), ('Y', 'W'), ('Y', "Y'"), ('Y', 'y'), ('y', "Y'")]` instead of just `WY',Wy,YY',Yy`. I also hope that is okay. If any of these conditions are an issue, just let me know, and I will fix them.

Comment: YW and WY are considered duplicates for this challenge, and it is therefor against the rules to print both of them. I have added a bit of clarification to the rules to avoid this in the future.

Comment: @NuffsaidM8 Actually. If you look closer, one of them is `W,"Y'"`, whereas the other is just `Y,W`. Like I said in my answer, those letters with an apostrophe in front of them will have a pair of quotes around them, so the "duplicates" you are talking about are not really duplicates. One of them is incomplete dominance, whereas the other signifies codominance.

Comment: I apologize, I was looking at the second and third output yet completely ignored the fact that one is a dominant y and one is recessive!